# Eigen: Is it possible to create LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner-like conditioner if i only can compute Aty and Ax?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, least-squares, eigen3

I want to solve least-squares like system `A^t * A * x = -A^t * x`. (I'm implementing Gauss-Newton method for special problem).

I wrote special routines which allow me to compute `A * x` and `A^t * y` products. With such routines it's easy to use matrix-free solvers thanks to Eigen.

But my approach converges not as good as `Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient`. I made a small test and it's looks like `LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner` speed ups convergence a lot.

My question is - how i can use `LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner` or implement own Preconditioner if i can only compute matrix products?
I'm not very good with understanding preconditioning/conjugate gradient stuff btw.

**EDIT**

For clarity - i want to use Matrix-free solvers from Eigen with my product routines.

**EDIT 2**

Matrix-vector products was obtained by using forward and reverse mode autodiff on some objective functions.

Comment: In my understanding, the preconditioner simply consists in replacing an equation Ax=b by AtAx=Atb, to get an equation with a symmetric positive-definite matrix. This allows to use iterative methods. You already have such a symmetric matrix. Difficult to answer you without more details about your implementation of the Gauss-Newton method

Comment: I don't understand if you want to use Eigen, or only a subset of Eigen functions, or no Eigen function at all

Comment: @Damien thank you for comment! I edited post - i want to use Eigen solvers with my product routines

Comment: @Damien as far as i know preconditioner scales matrix A (or AtA) and improves conditional number of matrix.

Comment: You have tested Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient which works well. So why not using it ?

Comment: @Damien Currently i'm using it. But obtaining matrix for my problem (jacobian for gauss newton) is super slow. In other hand obtaining  jacobian-vector product is pretty fast. So i want to utilize this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183289/discussion-between-damien-and-dark-daiver).

Comment: Is the actual question how to compute the diagonal of `A^t*A` or, if you have that, how to use this a preconditioner? The second problem is answered by @ggael, for the first problem you'd need to describe more about `A` (and maybe it will be more a math question than a programming question).

Comment: @chtz you are right. Should i create a post on math.stackexchange?
Do i understand correctly that there are no way to do it by only using `A`-vec products? Except performing N products by [1, 0, 0 ....] like vectors?
I obtained products by using forward and reverse mode autodiff on my objective function.

Comment: I don't see any obvious solution except computing the squared norm of each `A*Unit(i)` -- maybe you can accelerate computing these, since you know that only a single element is non-zero each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest might be to implement your own preconditioner class inheriting `DiagonalPreconditioner` and implementing something like `LeastSquareDiagonalPreconditioner ::factorize()` but adapted to your type. Basically you need to compute:

```
 m_invdiag(j) = 1./mat.col(j).squaredNorm();
```

for all column `j` using a strategy to what you already implemented for the product operators.